# how could i store pdf file in Ms Sql Server through Stored Procedure using C#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have tried to insert any file in to sql server database using c#,
for that i have converted file data to byte Array but i don't know how to read data from byte array Please suggest me some way to solve it out.

Comment: How do you want to use the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to do this.

Create a table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SavePDFTable](

  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [PDFFile] [varbinary](max) NULL
```

)

Then do the c# code like

```
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING"))
{
    cn.Open();
    FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead("C:\\MyFiles\\TempReport.pdf");
    byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
    fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
    fStream.Close();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into SavePDFTable " + "(PDFFile)values(@data)", cn))
   {
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", contents);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         Response.Write("Pdf File Save in Dab");
   }
```

}

Remove the "insert into SavePDFTable " + "(PDFFile)values(@data)" part and place your SP name.

Comment: this link include how to read as well http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/013102/save-and-read-pdf-file-using-sql-server-and-C-Sharp/